# How to type a vertical bar on a asus zenbook prime

Tags: keyboard, asus-laptop

I have a hopefully easy question to answer. How do you type the vertical bar character on an asus zenbook prime? It's situated in the bottom right corner of the 7 key, but I don't know how to access it. The manual for the notebook and the asus tutor program had nothing on the keyboard. Please help.

Comment: might help to post a picture of your keyboard - as far as I know the british and american layout put the pipe in different places

Comment: The answer is probably 'use the Fn key' Especially if the bar has the same colour as the Fn key (usually blue). But I have not found a picture of your keyboard to confirm that. (http://www.engadget.com/photos/asus-zenbook-prime-ux21a-preview/#5037867 has a nice picture of the keyboard of a Asus zenbook prime UX21A but that one has no such key. Could you update the post with the specific model?)

Comment: @Hennes I thought it would be the Fn key as well, but holding down that and pressing the 7 key just prints a 7. I think the model is a UX31A

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Its usually the <kbd>\</kbd> key with a shift - on the picture of the keyboard Hennes linked its the one below the backspace. If its on the bottom right, the <kbd>alt gr</kbd> key [[wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AltGr_key)] along with the key in question would do the trick

Comment: XD. I gotta know, was it alt-gr or shift \ ?

Comment: It was shift and \